# Does angular have any built-in package which tells if browser/window exists?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to know if browser/window exists or its only server that is running, for now I am using this :

```
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {

}
```

It's good, but I would love to have something that I could subscribe and wait till browser window appears and then call the function.

Comment: Are you trying to detect server side rendering?

Comment: Yes, I use SSR and i would like to detect if its server / browser.